# How to run a mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

```
       <?php

// Forum Configuration
define('DB_HOST','localhost'); // Database Hostname
define('DB_USER','root'); // Database Username
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); // Database Password
define('DB_NAME','ultraforum'); // Database Name
define('WEB_NAME','Website Name'); // Website Name
define('WEB_TITLE','Website Title'); // Website Title

// Do not modify anything under this line :)

    class db {

    var $dbhost;
    var $dbuser;
    var $dbpassword;
    var $dbname;
    var $query;

        function connect() {

            $this->db = 
                new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $this->dbname);

        }

        function __construct() {
            $this->dbhost = DB_HOST;
            $this->dbuser = DB_USER;
            $this->dbpassword = DB_PASSWORD;
            $this->dbname = DB_NAME;
        }

    }

    $con = new db;
    $con->connect();
    $con->query("SELECT * FROM topics");
```

Still doesnt work and gives me an error **Fatal error: Call to undefined method db::query() in C:\wamp\www\CodeCanyon\Ultra Forum\core\Config.php on line 39**

I just started with php object oriented programming, I made my connection class (using `mySQLi`) but I still don't understand how to run a query?

Comment: Doesn't the tutorial or book or whatever took you this far tell you?

Comment: Thats not really helpful :/

Comment: No, really, it seems strange that something tells you how to make a connection but not how to do anything with it.

Comment: PHP has a manual that perfectly explains the usage. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: sorry i used :: instead of -> try it again now

Comment: `MySQLi` is already a class with all the bells and whistles you will need. Why are you creating a `db` class? It just envelops it and does not do anything.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen oh, you cannot be more wrong. It's just impossible to use bare mysqli in the real life. A wrapper class is a must.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You are right, but the MySQLi object is not wrapped in this code, it is used directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con = new db;
$con->connect();
$con->db->query("SELECT * FROM topics");
```

But the class seems quite useless yet.

Comment: Thanks, resolved my issues. I already had figured the connection part but had problems with running the query as I was doing $con->query("SELECT * FROM topics"); instead of $con->db->query("SELECT * FROM topics");

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $con->db->query("SELECT * FROM topics");
```